# Stack/package robot_setup_tf not found

Tags: ros, catkin, broadcaster, robot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I'm new to ROS. I'm tasked to Hokuyo UST-20LX's laser scan to scan area.

I'm stuck with the robot_setup_tf part. I have already set up my workspace environment with:

```
~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
```

and to confirm:

```
~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

I get:

```
/home/gordon/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

Afterwards I did catkin_make and catkin_make install (no error) and tried to run:

```
rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster
```

It gives me:

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package robot_setup_tf not found
```

I suspect the problems lies with the environment configuration (just my guess) and ran:

```
~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

and I got:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

Any problems with the environment setup? If not, what is the problems with not being able to start up tf_broadcaster?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211427/stack/package-robot_setup_tf-not-found/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Afterwards I did catkin_make and catkin_make install (no error) and tried to run: `rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster`. It gives me:
>
> ```
> [rospack] Error: stack/package robot_setup_tf not found
> ```
>
> I suspect the problems lies with the environment configuration (just my guess) and ran: `~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, and I got:
>
> ```
> /opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
> ```

Catkin does out-of-source builds, which is why you need to source other *spaces* like `devel`. Since you ran `catkin_make install`, all build artefacts will be installed into the `install` space. That space has its own `setup.bash`, so you'll need to source that, but only *after* you've ran `catkin_make install`.

I don't see a `source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash` in your OP, so I'm guessing you didn't do that.

See [wiki/catkin/workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces) for more info on catkin workspaces in general, and on catkin *spaces* in particular. [REP-128](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html) is the more normative reference for this.

PS: running `catkin_make install` isn't actually necessary to execute nodes in your workspace. A regular `catkin_make` results in a `devel` space that can already be used. Just `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after building your workspace. No need to `install` anything.

PPS: this is completely up to you of course, but I'd not use Groovy anymore. It EOL-ed for some time now, so no updated and / or fixes will be released for it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-16**:
Oh I get it. I sourced back devel/setup.bash and run rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster , it works. Thanks a lot!